# How to change sizing of graphs in R?

Tags: r, xcode, graph, resize, pie-chart

I have made a collection of pie graphs and their sizing needs to be different. the image is currently distorted. How do I change the sizing?

[image: the distroted graphs]

```
x1 <- c(90,7,3)
x2 <- c(70,18,12) 
x3 <- c(17,4,30,17,30) 
label1 <- c('Physically 90%','Spoke 7%','Never 3%')
label2 <- c('Abrupt Stop 70%','Go Around 18%','Stops Far \nAway 12%')
label3 <- c('None 17','Robot-Robot 4%','Robot-\nHuman 30%','Robot-\nObject 17%','Robot-\nSurface 30%')
par(mfrow = c(2,2)) 
pie(x1, label1,main="Instances Where Robot Has Been Stuck", col=rainbow(length(x1)))
pie(x2, label2,main="How Robot Avoids Objects", col=rainbow(length(x2)))
pie(x3, label3,main="Collision Types", col=rainbow(length(x3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x1 <- c(90,7,3)
x2 <- c(70,18,12) 
x3 <- c(17,4,30,17,30) 
label1 <- c('Physically 90%','Spoke 7%','Never 3%')
label2 <- c('Abrupt Stop 70%','Go Around 18%','Stops Far \nAway 12%')
label3 <- c('None 17','Robot-Robot 4%','Robot-\nHuman 30%','Robot-\nObject 17%','Robot-\nSurface 30%')
par(mfrow = c(2,2)) 
pie(x1, label1,main="Instances Where Robot Has Been Stuck", col=rainbow(length(x1)), radius=1.05)
pie(x2, label2,main="How Robot Avoids Objects", col=rainbow(length(x2)), radius=1.05)
pie(x3, label3,main="Collision Types", col=rainbow(length(x3)), radius=1.05)
```

You can add an argument in `pie`:
`radius=1.05` in order to adjust the size of the pie chart.

The documentation for pie is as below:

```
radius  
the pie is drawn centered in a square box whose sides range from -1−1 to 11. 
If the character strings labeling the slices are long 
it may be necessary to use a smaller radius.
```

[image]

You can also check this post:
[How to make a pie() chart larger in R without it cutting off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104407/how-to-make-a-pie-chart-larger-in-r-without-it-cutting-off)